# How to load html into hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I have a page setup with links that hide/show divs. The last link is a contact form. Contact forms are super messy with code so I wanted to load the file externally

I found many snippets on simply loading html into div with jquery. But the issue is I already have jquery setup to show and hide the divs

How can I have the contact link show the contact div and also load the external contact form into it?

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu').click(function () {
            var $clicked = $(this)
            $('.menu').each(function(){
                var $menu = $(this);
                if (!$menu.is($clicked))
                {
                    $($menu.attr('data-item')).hide();
                }
            });
            $($clicked.attr('data-item')).toggle();
        });
  $(".contactmenu").click(function(){
         $("#menu-contact").load("contactform.htm");
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div align="center" class="logoclass" id="logo"><img src="media/logo.png"/></div>
<div id="topmenu">
<a href="#" id="home-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-home">Home</a>
<a href="#" id="videos-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-videos">Videos</a>
<a href="#" id="follow-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-follow">Follow</a>
<a href="#" id="contact-menu-item" class="menu" data-item="#menu-contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</header>

<article>
<div id="bodycontent">
<div id="menu-contact" style="display: none">Contact</div>
<div id="menu-follow" style="display: none">Follow</div>
<div id="menu-videos" style="display: none"><br />
<div id="videos" style="z-index:1" onClick="document.getElementById('sitemusic').pause();"><br />
<div align="center" id="videobox">Splash
<video style="z-index:-1;" width="400" controls>
  <source src="media/videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/videos/splash.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu-home" style="display: none">..</div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: The live site is http://shadextracks.com so you can see what I am trying to do

Comment: If you want it to do multiple things then put multiple bit of code in there. What is the problem?

Comment: it does not matter ,  it is hidden or not

Comment: Yeah like @Nikola said, it doesnt matter if a div is hidden you can still add content to it. Or si there a particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: http://shadextracks.com/  - 403: Forbidden

Comment: The 403 has *nothing* to do with whether the div is hidden or not.  It's caused when you retrieve the data.  For example - what happens if you try it when the div is not hidden?

Answer (score 0):

contactmenu class doesn't exist, try:

```
$("#contact-menu-item").click(function(){
```

Comment: I forgot that was when I was testing out methods. Though I did try that and it still only displays the div content text. It doesn't load in the html form.